# static file url unexpected behavior

Tags: go

Can someone explain to me why the first line of code delivers the desired result and the second piece of code returns 404? In the browser I searched localhost/ and localhost/css respectively.

```
1. http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))) // works
2. http.Handle("/css", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))) // fails
```

1. returns the .css file at desired url (localhost/).
2. returns 404 at desired url (localhost/css).

I am not trying to serve both URLs at the same time. I comment out one or the other while I am trying to figure this out.

Comment: This is what [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) refers to as a "subtree". A trailing slash in the route will match anything with that prefix; without the trailing slash, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The code below returned my css at the desired URL.

```
http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css))))
```

What's odd is I could have sworn I tried this method. Must be something delaying the refresh of chrome.